# Devise authentication for polymorphic solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Consider an application, which needs to have two different types of user:

- `User` as in standard client
- `Organization` as an entity offering some services through the application

Requirements:

- different standard controllers (sessions, registrations etc)
- access to different parts of the application of course

This seems like a walk in the park by simply creating two separate models with `devise`, but I really wouldn't like to duplicate so much functionality for authentication.

I went with a polymorphic association, where `Organization` and `User` are different models, both with a 1-1 relation with `Entity` representing authentication. `Entity` only has `devise` attributes (like password etc), while others have type-specific ones. Unfortunately this solution comes with a lot of drawbacks, like having to define custom helpers, `warden` strategies and `devise` failure apps.

I'm wondering, is there a concise solution for this type of issue?

Ideally, something like having two `devise` models delegating everything regarding authentication to a separate entity.

Comment: I have the same question, I need to build a lot of custom helpers